# how to get logged in user inside model for mongoose virtual attribute

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to define a virtual attribute called 'perms' on a JobSchema.

```
JobSchema.virtual('perms').get(function(){
    var perms = {}
        , userId = user._id
        , userRole = user.role
        , hasModify = userRole === 'admin' || this.creator && userId.id == this.creator.id;

    perms.delete = hasModify;
    perms.edit = hasModify;

    return perms;
});
```

I don't know how to get access to `user` which is the logged in user. It can be accessed from `req.user` but I don't know how to pass it to the virtual attributes get method.

edit: I decided to use an instance method and set the perms explicitly on the model instance.

```
//controller

job._doc.perms = job.getPerms(user);


//model

JobSchema.method('getPerms', function(user){
    var perms = {}
        , hasModify = false;

    if ( user ) {
        hasModify = user.get('role') === 'admin' || this.creator && user.get('id') === this.creator.get('id');
    }

    perms.edit = hasModify;
    perms.delete = hasModify;

    return perms;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this inside mongoose model. Mongoose model holds data just relative to the loaded instance. **req.user** or **req.session.user** are usually provided by passport or some other middleware. You would have to make this check per request.

You can try adding middleware in the app though:

`app.use(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user.role === 'admin') {
         req.user.perms = ...
    } else {
         req.user.perms = ...
    }
    next();
}`

Just make sure you add this middleware *after* passport or whatever is used for authentication.

Comment: this won't work because permissions are dependent on who created the model if they are not the admin. I created an instance method `job.getPerms(user)` that returns the permissions, then I do `job._doc.perms = job.getPerms(user)`.

Comment: Well it will be tricky in any way you put it. req.user is a per-request thing, you cannot know that in advance. model.perms is a per-model thing.
I'm not sure about virtuals, but how about an instance method? Virtual makes stuff a bit more automatic, whereas with a instance method, you have to manually call it and save afterwards. But in your case, you might have no alternatives.

Comment: I've updated my example with what I decided to use. I'm just not sure if `job._doc.perms = job.getperms(user);` is the proper way to set an attribute not in the schema.

Comment: Hmm, no, it's more like _schema.methods.getPerms = function(user) {
    if(user && user.role === 'admin') {
        this._doc.perms = ...;
    }
};_ And you'd access it by _var job = new Job(options);  var perms = job.getPerms(req.user); job.save(...)_
So, schema.methods.something creates a method on an _instance_, and in it, you can call 'this' to get that instance. You can also do schema.statics.getPermsForUserAndJob, which is then used on the model, like _var model = require('./models/job.js'); model.getPermsForJobAndUser(job, user, callback);

Comment: Can you post an example? I'm not sure if this is going to cause problems doing this._doc.perms inside the getPerms. I don't want to actually save them, just annotate the object after I've already gotten it from the db before I output it as json.

Comment: This was not saving anything. You'd have to call this.save from the instance method.